# SQL Server DateDiff Vs .Net DateDiff

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME
SET @Date1 = '2012-26-12 12:00:05 AM'

DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME
SET @Date2 = '2012-28-12 12:00:00 AM'

SELECT @Date1, @Date2, DATEDIFF(DAY,@Date1,@Date2) 

return 2
```

VB.Net

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Convert.ToDateTime("26-12-2012 12:00:05 AM"), 
Convert.ToDateTime("28-12-2012 12:00:00 AM"))

return 1
```

Why are the results different? My two cents is that SQL Server's `DateDiff` subtracts only day part of the date time value (28 - 26) whereas .Net `DateDiff` precisely subtracts two date time values as seconds or milliseconds and converts into equivalent day value.

Or, is that because of operating system's regional and language settings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the VB.NET expression is returning you the correct values since the total number of `hours` is not equal to `48` .Hence it is returning 1

In SQL Server , DateDiff function returns a round off value .

Try dividing the value with total number of seconds in day which is `86400.0`

```
SELECT @Date1, @Date2, DATEDIFF(ss,@Date1,@Date2) /86400.0
```

The value returned will be `1.9999421` instead of `2`

The difference between the 2 date in seconds is `172795` which is less than `172800` (Total seconds for 2 days).Hence the function should be returning only 1 if your not rounding off the result

Answer (score 1):

`Day DateDiff` round down the number returned. Try to return hours and divide by 24 to get count of days

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour,Convert.ToDateTime("26-12-2012 12:00:05 AM"), 
Convert.ToDateTime("28-12-2012 12:00:00 AM"))/24
```