# How to get the difference of dates or TAT in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I want to get the Turn Around Time(TAT) of dates. for example:
I have a createddatetime `2016-11-02 06:21:34.000` and endeddatetime `2016-11-02 22:00:00.000`. I want to get the difference of two dates by 2 decimal places. Anyone can help for the SSRS expression needed to perform this? 
Result for the above diff is `0.67`

TIA!

Comment: What is the unit of 0.67? Hours? Days?

Comment: @grafgenerator this is my query in SQL heres how I did it.        CAST(DATEDIFF(hh,t.Route_Created,t.poended)/24.0 AS DECIMAL(5,2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With number formatting set to Number with 2 decimal places, this expression gives you the same result as your SQL statement:

`=Round(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second,Fields!FirstDate.Value,Fields!SecondDate.Value) /60 / 60, 0) / 24`

You need to calculate the number of seconds and round this as an hour value to emulate the behaviour of SQL's `DATEDIFF` function as the .NET version only considers complete units when comparing dates. See this question for further details of this: [SQL Server DateDiff Vs .Net DateDiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036532/sql-server-datediff-vs-net-datediff).

If you just used:

`=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!FirstDate.Value,Fields!SecondDate.Value)`

then you'll get a result of `0.00` as there are no complete days between these dates, rather than the `0.65` you get from the SQL statement.

Similarly, if you try:

`=DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour,Fields!FirstDate.Value,Fields!SecondDate.Value) / 24`

you'll get a result of `0.63`, as the number of complete hours between your dates is `15` and `15 / 24 = 0.625`.